# Can you have multiple Require.JS modules on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

What I want to do is have multiple modules to extend a web site.  and was wondering if I can have multiple self contained modules with their own instances of require.js

Example:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script src="module1/require.js" data-main="module1/main"></script>
    <script src="module2/require.js" data-main="module2/main"></script>
    ...
</head>
```

Also if I use different versions of jquery or some other lib, does it contain that lib to each individual module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but not in this way. You should separate module configuration and bootstrapping. By module configuration I mean calling to

`require.config({
   ...
});`

and by bootstrapping:

`require(['module/main']);`

See an example here:

[main.js](https://github.com/shustariov-andrey/angularjs-requirejs/blob/master/src/main.js)

[index.html](https://github.com/shustariov-andrey/angularjs-requirejs/blob/master/src/index.html)

[bootstrap.js](https://github.com/shustariov-andrey/angularjs-requirejs/blob/master/src/bootstrap.js)